# Power BI and Shared datasets how to allow users to create new measures and reports and publish

Tags: powerbi

We are having difficulty finding a method of sharing a dataset and allowing users to use that dataset to create and publish their own reports. This would include ability to create new measures (Dax) and then publish themselves. Using the "service" live connection does not seem to allow that and if not using that there seems to be an issue of refreshing the data once that dataset is downloaded and modified with new columns/measures etc.

Greatly appreciate any help on this. So far I have seen nothing that shows how to do any of this so I have to assume it may not be possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Connect to a Power BI Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets) allows for local measures.

If you need more modeling changes when working with a remote Data Set, the [DirectQuery for Power BI Datasets and AAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services) feature (currently in preview) enables you to mash-up remote Data Set tables, with local tables, and allows for adding calculated columns to remote tables.

But you should use this with some care, as the query processing is split between the local model and the remote model(s), which can cause performance issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not allow for any column tools which may be necessary.

Comment: Correct.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a lot to go through for just one user needing this functionality.  Is it possible to just give her the pbix file and have it store the credentials so we don't have to start giving out sql connection credentials which is not ideal either?

Comment: The user should have their own credentials, ideally using Windows Integrated security.  Or you can create Power BI Data Flows for the tables she needs and give her access to those.  Data Flows are the Power BI feature for publishing raw source data instead of finished analytical models. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-create

Comment: Thank you and yes we're looking into dataflows now. :)